# postgres - Get entries older than 24 hours

Tags: jquery, postgresql

I have this query but it gets entries that are within the last 24 hours and if they're older it doesn't get them at all.

What am I doing wrong:

```
SELECT "registered_at" FROM table WHERE "registered_at" > NOW() - INTERVAL '24 hours' limit 10;
```

Comment: Could you create a db-fiddle that also shows some data? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14

Comment: "older" would be `<` not `>`

Comment: What is the desired result?